# Why is 'this' not what I expect it to be?

Tags: javascript, object, this

## Why is 'this' not what I expect it to be?

Always thought I understood js closure pretty well and was too smart and sexy to run into a problem like this, but I'm ready to become an functional atheist...

### Observe the example code js Ninjas:

```
function Drawing (id, element) {
    /*
     * Section A: value of 'this' object of type 'Drawing' (expected);
     *  Variables I ought to have access to from any point in Drawing's invocation
     */
    { // Preconstruction
        var Drawing = this;
        var SVG = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', "SVG");
        support.dom.Associative.call(Drawing, id, element);
        element = Drawing.$(); // In case element was null
        element.className = "Drawing";
        // Things in or about the drawing
        var shapes = [];

    }


    function add (shape) {
        /*
         * Section B: value of 'this' Window object
         * What gives in this function?
         *  Variables I have access to from section A:
         *    element: yes, id: no, Drawing: no, SVG: yes
         *  ?$@#$%^$#!!!!! Help me!
         */
        if (shape instanceof Shape) {
            shapes.push(shape);
            if(!this.render) SVG.appendChild(shape.toSVG());
            return shape;
        }
    }


    this.modify = function (options) {
        if (options.create) {
            return add(create[options.create](options));
        }
    };
}
```

### What don't I get?

**`function add`** is defined in **`function Drawing`**, and in my wild application there is no other function named or defined add **`add'**.

The function I expect is in fact invoking, and I break inside it and see that I have access to *some* of the closure defined vars from Drawing's invocation, but not *all* or at least it seems this way.

Edumucate me please maybe I'm making a silly mistake and another pair of eyes will help... I'm ready to give up on science everything I know is wrong :)

Below is a cap of the spiritually offending output:
[image: Offensive Output, Parental Guidance Advised]

Comment: The "add" function does have access to the local variables in the closure. What makes you think it doesn't? And what do you expect that `this` will be in an invocation of "add"?  The only call to it is a "naked" invocation, so `this` would either be `undefined` or `window` depending on whether you're in "strict" mode.

Comment: I agree with you that it *should* have access to the local variables.  That's what I find so offensive about the code I wrote...

Comment: So that screenshot you just posted makes it quite clear that inside the "add" function the value of `this` is `window`.

Comment: I have written 100 000 lines of JS and never needed to define a function inside a function.

Comment: this *should* be an invocation of Drawing.  In another point of code, I've instanced a new Drawing.  But add is defined at Drawing's closure, so when I invoke add from inside Drawing's closure function, why is this not the Drawing?  I even usually create a var Drawing = this; line in most function classes I write to maintain closure, but that particualr var is undefined in add

Comment: @IvanKuckir It's a bit off topic, patterns do not change the way a language is built

Comment: @Ivan Kuckir lol ecma is functional, I do and I'm not not defining functions in functions.  Where is my closure?

Comment: K I figured it out anyway...  I replaced my reference to **`this`** with my afore-defined **`var Drawing = this;`** (A lot of people use the form **`var that = this`**) and the reference is there, despite it not being available to the inline console command line.

Comment: I am also gravely mistaken in assuming **`this`** has a whole lot to do with closure the more I think about it.

Comment: Can you put your actual question in the title of your post, please?

Comment: @IvanKuckir if you used more functions it'd probably be only 25,000 lines :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured out my error in thinking, and wrote a simple example below explaining my confusion:  hope this helps others!

```
function Class () {
    // this: an object with a prototype of Class, if 'new'ed, window otherwise
    var that = this;
    function privateMethod () {
        // this: a reference to window.  privateMethod still belongs to Class' closure
        var dat = this;

        // that: an object with a prototype of Class, if 'new'ed, window otherwise
        var dis = that;
    }
}
```

I replaced my reference to **`this`** with my afore-defined **`var Drawing = this;`** (A lot of people use the form **`var that = this`**) and the reference is there, despite it not being available to the inline console command line.

Appreciate the thought provoking convo that lead to the answer!

I believe again.